# PyQt Custom QSorfFilterProxyModel for filtering checked items

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am making a qt application with PyQt. I have a custom QTableModel that i show in a QTableView. Each row in this model can be checked, when a row is checked I want it to appear in another QTableView. To do this I made a custom proxymodel subclassing from QSortFilterProxyModel.
In my custom model I reimplemented the filterAcceptsRow method to only accept rows that are checked:

```
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, pos, index):

        model = self.sourceModel() # The sourcemodel is a 2d array of QStandardItem
        row = model.row(pos)  # This method returns the row at index pos
        if row[0].checkState(): # The first QStandardItem has a checkbox
            return True
        return False
```

This works once at the start of my program (I assume when i call setSourceModel) but doesn't update when the checked items change. How do I make sure this function gets called when the checkstate changes in my base model? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: When an item in your model is checked/unchecked the model needs to emit the relevant [`dataChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you, this was what I needed.